# Simple Music Visualisation with a Circle

Tags: android, audio, visualization

Im trying to build a simple Music Visualisation App which just should resize a Circle. So if the Music Part which is currently playing is loud it should get bigger and if not it should get smaller.

To Visualize the Circle I just created a custom View Class which draws the circle in the `onDraw` Method.

To get the informations out of the current Audio, I found the [Visualizer Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) of Android and also used the `setDataCaptureListener`.

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[0]);
mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
     new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
             public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                        mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
                    }

                    public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {

                    }
                }, (int)(Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 1.5), true, false);
```

But my Problem is that I don't really know how I use the byte Array which is given back, to find out the music change in general (got louder or not ?).

I just tried to get the average of the array but this gives me completely bad results. The circle changed his size like it is on drugs. So I thought maybe the array has too many outlined/extreme values (which was true) so I calculated the median of the array. This gaved me better results but still isn't what I want. It's not very smooth and it's to complex. I always have to sort the array which is not really efficient. What am I thinking wrong ?

Im really a beginner in this AudioFX section and Im completely sorry If this is a dumb question and attempt of me.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT:**

```
 private float schwelle = 5000;
 private float last = 0;
 ...

    float summe = 0;

    for (Byte currentByte: mBytes)
        summe += currentByte;

    if (summe > schwelle && summe > last)
    {
        last = summe; //make it bigger
    }
    else {
        last -= 100; //make circle smaller
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2,last / 100,mForePaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

A really good git project is https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer.
I myself came up with this:(it's a lot simple than the git solution)

You can use the values of the array to draw the the waveform on the outline of a circle using trigonometry, and make the start radius of the circle bigger if the sum of the array is bigger than certain treshhold:

```
class StarWaveformRenderer implements Renderer {
private Paint p = new Paint();

private static final int BOOST_TRASH_HOLD = 10000;


private float stretchFade = 1; //circle fades after a prominent beat

@Override
public void render(Canvas canvas, byte[] data) {
    if (data == null || data.length == 0)
        return;

    int centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
    float stretch = stretchFade;

    int sum = RenderUtils.sum(data);
    p.setColor((p.getColor() + sum / 2)); //change color of circle
    if (sum > BOOST_TRASH_HOLD) {//prominent beat

        stretch = (float) Math.min(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()) / Byte.MAX_VALUE / 3;  //maximum

        stretchFade = stretch;
    }

    double radDif = 2 * Math.PI / data.length;  //the angle between each element of the array
    double radPos = 0;

    float lX = (float) Math.cos(radPos) * data[0] + centerX;
    float lY = (float) Math.sin(radPos) * data[0] + centerY;
    float cX;
    float cY;


    for (byte b : data) {
        cX = (float) Math.cos(radPos) * b * stretch + centerX;
        cY = (float) Math.sin(radPos) * b * stretch + centerY;//calculate position of outline, stretch indicates promince of the beat

        canvas.drawLine(lX, lY, cX, cY, p);

        lX = cX;
        lY = cY;
        radPos += radDif;

    }


    stretchFade = Math.max(1, stretchFade / 1.2f);//beat fades out

}
```

}

You can programm your own renderes and let the user select which one he wants to use. Just pass the array from `onWaveformDataCapture` to the onRender method.

Utils for analysing the waveform (the amplitude is stored kind of weird):

```
class RenderUtils {
private static final byte SHIFT = Byte.MAX_VALUE;


static int sum(byte[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (byte b : data)
        sum += b;
    return sum;
}


static int toAmplitude(byte b) {
    return b > 0 ? b + SHIFT : -b;//+127=high positive;+1=low positive;-127=low negative;-1=high negative
}

static float toAmplitude(float f) {
    return f > 0 ? f + SHIFT : -f;//+127=high positive;+1=low positive;-127=low negative;-1=high negative
}
```

}

Comment: Hmm... Thank you for your help, I just tried to do it with the sum and the trashhold princip but it is still not what I want. Its not looking like a synchronized Circle. (I didnt add the fancy lines around the Circle :-) ). I updated my post with the code I tried.